# Retain Static IP address lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have assigned static IP to an instance in lightsail in Ireland Region, But I am moving that instance to another region is it possible to retain the Same static IP to the migrated instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Elastic IP addresses are linked to specific Regions.

Where possible, you should use **DNS Names** to point to IP addresses. This makes it easy to update an IP address when something changes. The only things that should refer to an IP address are DNS Names and security whitelists.